# add path permenantly on ubuntu for postgresql user

Tags: server, bash, python, postgresql

I am having trouble adding current PATH permanently on my ubuntu server for a postgresql user.

Every time I ssh or restart the server I have to run `export PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/.local/bin"`, I am running a python script which will not work unless this command is done so I tried a a simple addition of this in python but it didn't solve.

```
import os
cmd ='''export PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/.local/bin"'''
os.system(cmd)
... rest of my code
```

I also tried `sudo export PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/.local/bin"` but it gets removed after each restart what can I do to permanently add this path or make the python script run it.

Comment: In your home directory (or the home directory of your server) there is a file called ".bashrc", which probably is what you are asking for.

Comment: @GyroGearloose does it matter that I am doing it on postgresql user ?

Comment: "does it matter that I am doing it on postgresql user ?", yes, but not specifically. ".bashrc" in  the respective home directory is executed every time an new bash shell is opened. (Similar *rc-files exist for other shells). For a test, use some thing like "touch /tmp/diditwork" in your .bashrc to check if it is executed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your path change to .bashrc perhaps

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"
```

Notice there is no export or other fancy stuff in the line

Comment: should not add the current directory in the path, `~/.local/bin` is added automatically on existence from `~/.profile`, and last, it's the wrong order, preferable is to have custom path first

Comment: @bac0n Yes, that directory should be added to the path automatically if it exists when you log in. There an if then statement that adds this directory.

Comment: @mchid the directory does exist why else would it work when I manually run the command. I believe the issue have to do with the fact that the use is a postgres user

Comment: @User19 Yes, I was wondering why it wasn't automatically working. The other place to add this is to your `~/.bashrc` file like in this answer but you would have to log out and log back in to verify if it works.

Comment: @mchid yes, it worked that way.